# How to create randomly generated strings in JavaScript that keep generating

Tags: javascript, string, loops, forever

```
var len = 20,
    str = '';

while( len-- ) {
    str += String.fromCharCode( 48 + ~~(Math.random() * 42) );
}

console.log( str );
```

How would I change this code so that I can generate any amount of these strings that I want?

Comment: Maybe you could wrap it in a function

Answer (score 1):

If you make a function to generate random strings you can call it multiple times to generate different outputs. You can also make the length of the string a parameter of the function. I would also suggest using a for loop to make your code cleaner.

```
function randomString(var len)  {
    str = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
        str += String.fromCharCode( 48 + ~~(Math.random() * 42) );
    }
    return str;
}

console.log( randomString(20) );
```

Answer (score 0):

put it inside a loop structure.

```
 var num=0;
 do{
 var len = 20,
 str = '';
 while( len-- ) {
     str += String.fromCharCode( 48 + ~~(Math.random() * 42) );
 }
 console.log( "the: "+str );
 num++;
 }while(num<20)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function generateString () {
    var len = 20,
    str = '';

    while(len--) {
        str += String.fromCharCode( 48 + ~~(Math.random() * 42) );
    }

    console.log( str );
}

var noOfStringsToGenerate = 10;
for (i = 0; i < noOfStringsToGenerate.length; i++) { generateString() }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap it in a function and call `setInterval` if you want a new string every so often. Assign the `setInterval` call to a value in case you want to clear it at some point.

```
function getString() {

 var len = 20,
 str = '';

while( len-- ) {
    str += String.fromCharCode( 48 + ~~(Math.random() * 42) );
}

console.log( str );

}

var int = setInterval(getString, 100);
```